# Какими способами можно реализовать разрывистый border

Tags: css3, html5

Какими способами можно реализовать разрывистый border, как на рисунке, на одной линии со звёздами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это, скорее всего, не бордер, а линии на псевдоэлементах

Comment: Возможно. Есть мысли, что это 2 дива не имеющих высоту, обрамлённые бордером и имеющие "резиновую" ширину. Пока пробую

Comment: Всё верно, это псевдоэлементы. Оставлю ссылку если кому понадобится http://frontblog.ru/verstka-zagolovoka-s-liniyami-po-bokam-na-css.html